# unshare command doesn't create new PID namespace

Tags: namespaces, linux-namespaces

I'm learning linux core and I'm on the namepsaces topic now.
I tried to play with "unshare" command just to get hang of namespace and its essentials.
The problem is that it doesn't or, what is more probable, I'm doing something wrong.
I'd appreciate if you could help me to understand.
I try to execute busybox sh program as within its own PID namespace. That's what I do:

```
[ab@a ~]$ sudo unshare --pid  busybox sh
/home/ab # ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
6014 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo
6016 pts/1    00:00:00 busybox
6026 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

So as I can see it from the output of the ps command all process are visible in the new env. And it gets confirmed when I check pid namespace id of newly created process and current one. See below

```
[ab@a ~]$ ps -p 6016,$$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
4604 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
6016 pts/1    00:00:00 busybox
[ab@a ~]$ sudo ls -l /proc/4604/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ab ab 0 Aug  8 23:49 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ab ab 0 Aug  8 23:49 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ab ab 0 Aug  8 23:49 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ab ab 0 Aug  8 23:49 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ab ab 0 Aug  8 23:49 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ab ab 0 Aug  8 23:49 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
[ab@a ~]$ sudo ls -l /proc/6016/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug  9 00:07 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug  9 00:07 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug  9 00:07 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug  9 00:07 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug  9 00:07 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug  9 00:07 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

So, pid namespace stays the same eventhough I provided --pid argument to unshare call.
Could you please help me to understand why it happens.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

you should add `--fork` and `--mount-proc` switch to `unshare` as stated in the man page

> ```
> -f, --fork
>           Fork the specified program as a child process of unshare rather than running it directly. This is useful
>           when creating a new PID namespace. Note that when unshare is waiting for the child process, then it
>           ignores SIGINT and SIGTERM and does not forward any signals to the child. It is necessary to send
>           signals to the child process.
> ```

### Explanation (from `man pid_namespaces`)

> a process's PID namespace membership is determined when the process is created and cannot be changed thereafter.

what `unshare` actually does when you supply `--pid` is setting the file descriptor at `/proc/[PID]/ns/pid_for_children` for the current process to the new PID namespace, causing children subsequently created by this process to be places in a different PID namespace  (**its children not itself!! important!**).

So, when you supply `--fork` to `unshare`, it will fork your program (in this case `busybox sh`) as a child process of unshare and place it in the new PID namespace.

#### Why do I need `--mount-proc` ?

Try running unshare with only `--pid` and `--fork` and let's see what happen.

> ```
> wendel@gentoo-grill ~ λ sudo unshare --pid --fork busybox sh
> /home/wendel # echo $$
> 1
> /home/wendel # ps
> PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
> 12443 root      0:00 unshare --pid --fork busybox sh
> 12444 root      0:00 busybox sh
> 24370 root      0:00 {ps} busybox sh
> .
> .
> . // bunch more
> ```

from `echo $$` we can see that the pid is actually 1 so we know that we must be in the new PID namespace, but when we run `ps` we see other processes as if we are still in the parent PID namespace.

This is because of `/proc` is a special filesystem called `procfs` that kernel created in memory, and from the man page.

> A `/proc` filesystem shows (in the `/proc/[pid]` directories) only processes visible in the PID namespace of the process that performed the mount, even if the `/proc` filesystem is viewed from processes in other namespaces.

So, in order for tools such as `ps` to work correctly, we need to re-mount `/proc` using a process in the new namespace.

But, assuming that your process is in the root mount namespace, if we re-mount `/proc`, this will mess up many things for other processes in the same mount namespace, because now they can't see anything (in `/proc`). So you should also put your process in new mount namespace too.

Good thing is unshare has `--mount-proc`.

> ```
> --mount-proc[=mountpoint]
>           Just before running the program, mount the proc filesystem at mountpoint (default is /proc). This is useful when creating a new PID namespace. It also implies creating a new mount namespace since the /proc mount would
>           otherwise mess up existing programs on the system. The new proc filesystem is explicitly mounted as private (with MS_PRIVATE|MS_REC).
> ```

Let's verify that `--mount-proc` also put your process in new mount namespace.

bash outside:

> ```
> wendel@gentoo-grill ~ λ ls -go /proc/$$/ns/{user,mnt,pid}
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 Aug  9 10:05 /proc/17011/ns/mnt -> 'mnt:[4026531840]'
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 Aug  9 10:10 /proc/17011/ns/pid -> 'pid:[4026531836]'
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 Aug  9 10:10 /proc/17011/ns/user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
> ```

busybox:

> ```
> wendel@gentoo-grill ~ λ doas ls -go /proc/16436/ns/{user,mnt,pid}
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 Aug  9 10:05 /proc/16436/ns/mnt -> 'mnt:[4026533479]'
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 Aug  9 10:04 /proc/16436/ns/pid -> 'pid:[4026533481]'
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 Aug  9 10:17 /proc/16436/ns/user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
> ```

Notice that their user namespace is the same but mount and pid aren't.

Note: You can see that I cited a lot from man pages. If you want to learn more about linux namespaces (or anything unix really) first thing for you to do is to read the man page of each namespace. It is well written and really informative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply! It really helps. Could you please clarify one more thing for me. Why I can see from the bash outside that busybox is still in the same pid namespace while executing ls -l /proc/$$/ns from the busybox gives different pid namespace id? Does it mean that I can not see pid namespaces ids of a container from the host?

Comment: @AndrewBolotov Sorry I don't quite understand your question. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Thanks, looks like my I provided wrong PID while checking PID Namespace ID and this where confusion comes from.

Comment: Superb answer. only thing that I want to add is that `pid_for_children` was add in Linux 4.12.